# How to make CRM 2011 work in IE11 without IE 10 compatibility mode?

Tags: internet-explorer, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

We're trying to run custom page in iframe in CRM 2011. However, content within that iframe will not work in IE11 in compatibility mode IE10, which CRM 2011 is using for all it's host pages.

Since IE10 (or IE9) it's not possible to run frames in differnet compatibility mode, you can only change Standard Layout to Quirks Layout in it (according to documentation and googling session).

So we figured out, why not run CRM 2011 in IE11 mode? Since it can run in Edge browser then surely it will work, right?

Unfortunately, if we run CRM 2011 in IE11 in IE11 mode then a lot of CRM's javascript is failing.

So my question here is this:

Have anyone successfully ran CRM 2011 in IE11 in IE11 mode? Is there a polyfill  or some other way that will take care of internal CRM's javascript so that it will stop throwing errors?

Comment: "FYI"? Seriously? "FYI"? Do you think any web developer doesn't know that? 

Yes, we're in the middle of upgrade from crm to a original spa, but it's going to be gradual with new subpages shared between new spa app and old crm in iframe. This is why I'm asking.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 Update Rollup 17 introduces compatibility with Internet Explorer 11 when it runs in Windows 8.1 or Windows 7, have you tried the below link?

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2915687/microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011-update-rollup-17

Comment: This makes IE11 run in IE10 compatibility mode. We're on UR 18. :)

Comment: Hello Sztrzask, if you're using UR 18, it should be OK for IE11. From my experience,  we can solve this issue from these two options:1. we might using unsupported js code, find the alternative codes for it. 2. IE11 has enterprise mode to provide more compatibilities, we should test with it and find a working mode for us. https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/189193

Comment: It is ok for IE 11, but it runs in compatibility mode IE10. What we need is to make it run without compatibility mode - and when we do that, a lot of crm's javascript fails. We're going most likely to patch it ourselves but we were hoping that perhaps there's a polyfill/patch already there.Or a setting. Or whatever.

Comment: Hi Sztrzask, sorry for the delay response. I've reached our CRM support team, they've confirmed that there is no other patch/polyfill for 2011. Their suggestion is that it should be some compatibility issue in JS code, need to fix it from codes